# java.lang.IllegalStateException while removing an element from the list based on another list<Double> Java

Tags: java

I have searched in the internet but I  haven't found a question or solution dealing with this specific kind of problem although there are many with slightly different questions.So I came up here hoping for a solution.

I am not sure how to solve this and I have a feeling that this code is not good enough.

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Doubles;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
public List<City> getCitiestoVisit(List<City> cities,int totaldays) {
    ArrayList<Integer> w=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> p=new ArrayList<Integer>();      
    for(City c:cities){
        w.add((int) c.getCoverage());
        p.add(c.getScore());
    }
    days_incities = Ints.toArray(w);
    priority_scores = Ints.toArray(p);
    KnapsackInterface k = new FractionalKnapsack();
    double visit[] = k.optimize(days_incities, priority_scores, totaldays);
    List<Double> list = Doubles.asList(visit);
    System.out.println(visit.length);
    Iterator<City> iterc = cities.iterator();
    Iterator<Double> iterd = list.iterator();
    while(iterc.hasNext() && iterd.hasNext()){
        if(iterd.next().intValue()==0){
            iterc.remove();
        }
    }
    return cities;
}
```

I have 2 questions.If possible please do answer both.
Scenario is I have a city list where city is a user defined object and it contains an attribute 'coverage' time. The method above accepts cities and totaldays as arguments. So I felt the knapsack algorithm was suitable enough since I had to optimize the time with given total number of days. 
The point here is that knapsack method takes only integer arguments and returns a double array variable that contains values in fraction. Now I have successfully been able to pass it to the knapsack method by converting array to list and so. But my problem is  I am not able to remove element based on the the above condition that is if the visit[] list contains 0 then its corresponding element in the city must be deleted.

Question1 : Please suggest a suitable solution to delete the corresponding city in the cities list
Question2 : I have too many conversions from primitive types to List types. Is there any way where same functionality could be achieved in a better method. Please do suggest. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never calling `iterc.next()`. You can't call `iterc.remove()` if you have never called `iterc.next()` before. That is the reason you are getting `IllegalStateExceltion`. If you add `iterc.next()` before `if(iterd.next().intValue()==0)` problem of exception will be solved.

For the second question, you can avoid a couple of conversions by initializing `w` and `p` as `int` arrays instead of `ArrayList`.